# Preg replace issue (PHP)

Tags: php, preg-replace

I really need help with `preg_replace`. See below:

```
<html>[sourcecode language='php']<?php echo "hello world"; ?>[/sourcecode]</html>
```

I only want it to display the PHP tags and strip the rest out, so I would get the following result:

```
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
```

Please help. I have tried the following:

```
$update = get_the_content(); 

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/<html>/';
$patterns[1] = '/</html>/';
$patterns[2] = '/[sourcecode language]/';
$patterns[3] = '/[/sourcecode]/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '';
$replacements[1] = '';
$replacements[2] = '';
$replacements[3] = '';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $update);
```

But it doesn't work. My issue also is the language might not always be PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape chars like / when using / as a delimiter and [] as they have uses in regex:

```
$update = get_the_content(); 

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/<html>/';
$patterns[1] = '/<\/html>/';
$patterns[2] = '/\[sourcecode language\]/';
$patterns[3] = '/\[\/sourcecode\]/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '';
$replacements[1] = '';
$replacements[2] = '';
$replacements[3] = '';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape your square-brackets.  In regular expressions, `[` and `]` are the tags that indicate a *character class*, and the pattern is matching any one of those characters within the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

why not a different approach:

get all php tags and content

```
$src = get_the_content();
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(<\?php(?:.*)\?>)/i',$src,$matches);
echo implode("\n",$matches);
```

or get all contents of [sourcecode] blocks

```
$src = get_the_content();
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\[sourcecode[^\]]*\](.*)\[\/sourcecode\]/i',$src,$matches);
echo implode("\n",$matches);
```